# Is it better to keep DatabaseHelper open or close and re open on android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an android app that constantly inputs data on a database (sqlite).
every 3 or 6 seconds (sometime is less than that) I insert data into the DB.
I created a DatabaseHelper (SQLiteOpenHelper) object which does that but I've been wondering if its better to close and create a new DatabaseHelper object each time I input data or if its better to keep it open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use a single connection throughout your whole app, [it's explanied here](https://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection).
Also you could use [ORM Lite](https://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml).

But keep in mind that you should use [ROOM](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room), from Android documentation:

> We highly recommended using the Room Persistence Library as an
> abstraction layer for accessing information in your app's SQLite
> databases.